# Retrieve the last values entered in an input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm trying to implement a fallback function in javascript to the HTML5 search input.

I use Modermizr to detect the browsers who doesn't support this feature and jQuery to develop the fallback function.

First of all, i thought to add the autocomplete attribute to the input but this one is not supported by all browers (Internet Explorer for example).

Then i had the idea to use the jQuery-UI autocomplete Widget but you need to give it the values to display.

My question is how i could retrieve the last values entered in the input to after be able to display them with the jQuery-UI Widget?

Comment: You mean you want to use the native browsers stored values as your autocomplete source? Can't do it.

Comment: Or find an other way to propose the last values entered to the user, like with the HTML5 search input.